# Spring JPA @Autowired field is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to write a simple application that saves an entity into a PostgreSQL database. I use Spring data JPA, configuring it with xml. But seems something is going wrong and autowired field is not initialized.

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <jpa:repositories base-package="com.springjpa.repo" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
      <value>application.properties</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="${spring.datasource.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${spring.datasource.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${spring.datasource.password}"/>
  </bean>


  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springjpa" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mainBean" class="com.springjpa.controller.SpringJpaApp"/>

</beans>
```

SpringJpaApp.java

```
@Configuration
public class SpringJpaApp {

  @Autowired
  CustomerRepository customerRepository;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    try {
      ctx.refresh();
      SpringJpaApp s = (SpringJpaApp) ctx.getBean("mainBean");
      s.process();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  public String process() {
    // save a single Customer
    customerRepository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Smith"));

    // save a list of Customers
    customerRepository
        .save(Arrays.asList(new Customer("Adam", "Johnson"), new Customer("Kim", "Smith"),
            new Customer("David", "Williams"), new Customer("Peter", "Davis")));

    return "Done";
  }

}
```

CustomerRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

  List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

At the point I'm trying to access customerRepository I get NullPointerException.

Adding stacktrace.

```
16:10:32.411 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - Database ->
       name : PostgreSQL
    version : 9.5.12
      major : 9
      minor : 5
16:10:32.411 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - Driver ->
       name : PostgreSQL Native Driver
    version : PostgreSQL 9.1 JDBC4 (build 901)
      major : 9
      minor : 1
16:10:32.411 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - JDBC version : 4.0
16:10:32.411 [main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
16:10:32.454 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver - Unable to use Java 1.7 Connection#getSchema : An error occurred trying to resolve the connection default schema resolver: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.getSchema() is not yet implemented.
16:10:32.454 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl - Unable to resolve connection default schema
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Use of DefaultSchemaNameResolver requires Dialect to provide the proper SQL statement/command but provided Dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect] did not return anything from Dialect#getCurrentSchemaCommand
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver$SchemaNameResolverFallbackDelegate.resolveSchemaName(DefaultSchemaNameResolver.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver.resolveSchemaName(DefaultSchemaNameResolver.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.determineCurrentSchemaName(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:149)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at com.springjpa.controller.SpringJpaApp.main(SpringJpaApp.java:26)
16:10:32.454 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.IdentifierHelperBuilder - JDBC driver metadata reported database stores quoted identifiers in neither upper, lower nor mixed case
16:10:32.457 [main] INFO org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:149)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at com.springjpa.controller.SpringJpaApp.main(SpringJpaApp.java:26)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:753)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.createClob(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:52)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.createClob(Jdbc4Connection.java:21)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
16:10:32.458 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Namespace - Created database namespace [logicalName=Name{catalog=null, schema=null}, physicalName=Name{catalog=null, schema=null}]
16:10:32.458 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration pg-uuid -> org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType@3fc9dfc5
16:10:32.458 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.util.UUID -> org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType@3fc9dfc5
16:10:32.458 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@7d898981
16:10:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.spi.LoadPlanTreePrinter - LoadPlan(entity=com.springjpa.model.Customer)
    - Returns
       - EntityReturnImpl(entity=com.springjpa.model.Customer, querySpaceUid=<gen:0>, path=com.springjpa.model.Customer)
    - QuerySpaces
       - EntityQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:0>, entity=com.springjpa.model.Customer)
          - SQL table alias mapping - customer0_
          - alias suffix - 0_
          - suffixed key columns - {id1_0_0_}

16:10:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader - Static select for entity com.springjpa.model.Customer [NONE]: select customer0_.id as id1_0_0_, customer0_.firstname as firstnam2_0_0_, customer0_.lastname as lastname3_0_0_ from customer customer0_ where customer0_.id=?
16:10:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.QuerySpacesImpl - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:0> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@32a2a6be]
16:10:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : firstName
16:10:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path : lastName
16:10:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.FetchStyleLoadPlanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy - Building LoadPlan...
16:10:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor - processing queryspace <gen:0>
16:10:32.480 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.spi.LoadPlanTreePrinter - LoadPlan(entity=com.springjpa.model.Customer)
    - Returns
       - EntityReturnImpl(entity=com.springjpa.model.Customer, querySpaceUid=<gen:0>, path=com.springjpa.model.Customer)
    - QuerySpaces
       - EntityQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:0>, entity=com.springjpa.model.Customer)
          - SQL table alias mapping - customer0_
          - alias suffix - 0_
          - suffixed key columns - {id1_0_0_}
16:10:32.514 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'customerRepository'
16:10:32.514 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0'
16:10:32.514 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
16:10:32.514 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
16:10:32.514 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'transactionManager'
16:10:32.514 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'transactionManager' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'transactionManager'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'transactionManager'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'mainBean'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'mainBean'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'mainBean' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'mainBean'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0'
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@3238e2aa]
16:10:32.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
16:10:32.516 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
16:10:32.516 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
16:10:32.516 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
16:10:32.516 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mainBean'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.springjpa.controller.SpringJpaApp.process(SpringJpaApp.java:38)
    at com.springjpa.controller.SpringJpaApp.main(SpringJpaApp.java:28)
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: Sure will add, sorry.

Comment: Why you use the old style XML configuration not the annotationbased way?

Comment: Is the repository located in the package `com.springjpa.repo`

Comment: Yes it is in the right package.

Comment: To start with, use Spring Boot for any new projects--it's the modern way of doing things and avoids many of these problems.

Answer (score 0):

The createClob failure!

try to disable jdbc metadta : Add this line to your applicationContext

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false" />
```

if your using boot :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
```